# how to get the oldest file in a directory fast using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have a directory with around 15-30 thousand files. I need to just pull the oldest one. In other words the one that was created first. Is there a quick way to do this using C#, other than loading them into a collection then sorting?

Comment: It was my understanding that having a large number of files in a directory reduces performance. It think you're way past that point.

Comment: Uhm, what John said.  Add some slashes to break it up into subdirectories.

Comment: Unless you need to do that several times a second, 15–30k aren't that many files.

Comment: Well, the right answer is to read the whole list in, keep it sorted, and don't touch the drive until it runs low.

Comment: @Johannes: it's not many files. It's many files in the same directory. _How_ bad this is will depend on the operations performance on that directory: many creates, deletes and renames will make this much worse. Note how Temporary Internet Files is broken up, and consider that to be a hint.

Comment: @John: Temporary internet files was designed at a different time and had to run well on a different file system, too. It's really not many files for NTFS, especially not if you're just enumerating them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is **no**. Windows file systems don't index files by date so there is no native way to do this, let alone a .net way without enumerating all of them.

Comment: What about FileSystemInfo object?

Answer (score 27):

You will have to load the FileInfo objects into a collection & sort, but it's a one-liner:

```
FileSystemInfo fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath).GetFileSystemInfos()
    .OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime).First();
```

Ok, two lines because it's a long statement.

Comment: Great simple answer. It won't get better than this without a change in the directory structure IMO.

Comment: Never sort a collection if your objective is only to return a single item. Use Aggregate() instead.  For an example, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120944/c-sharp-finding-nearest-number-in-array/13896732#13896732

Comment: @LeeGrissom thanks for the link; I'd not really considered any overhead before, as I assumed the `OrderBy` was lazy and wouldn't be evaluated entirely, but hadn't tested or checked.

Comment: Great answer, but, of course, `OrderByDescending` returns the NEWEST file first. To get the oldest file, as OP needed, just change to `OrderBy`. Also, i'd prefer `FirstOrDefault` to avoid an exception just in case the directory might be empty some day.

Comment: Why does this even have upvotes? If the files are created by the system, it is not able to tell the REAL oldest file because it does not look closely enough on the timestamp. If two files are created with only some ms timespan inbetween, it will NOT be able to tell the older one!
Second, this "solution" is simply WRONG because it returns the LATEST, not the oldest file! Use OrderBy, not [..]Descending

Comment: This answer was edited by another user to fix the problem commented above. Now it's using First() and OrderByDescending() to get the oldest.

Comment: Mods rejected my edit. I've tested this code, and it returns the newest file, not the oldest.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it without sorting but what you can do is make it fast.

Sorting by `CreationTime` can be slow because first accessing this property for each file involves interrogation of the file system.

Use [A Faster Directory Enumerator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/FastDirectoryEnumerator.aspx) that preserves more information about files while enumerating and allows to do sorting faster.

Code to compare performance:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var oldestFile = FastDirectoryEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\windows\system32")
        .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime).First();

    timer.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(oldestFile);
    Console.WriteLine("FastDirectoryEnumerator - {0}ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine();

    timer.Reset();
    timer.Start();

    var oldestFile2 = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\windows\system32").GetFiles()
        .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime).First();

    timer.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(oldestFile2);
    Console.WriteLine("DirectoryInfo - {0}ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to finish");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

For me it gives this:

> VEN2232.OLB
>
> FastDirectoryEnumerator - 27ms
>
> VEN2232.OLB
>
> DirectoryInfo - 559ms

Comment: All I can say is WoW - ShamWoW! Thanks a lot for this, I will certainly implement this.

Comment: @Konstantin: In .NET 4.0, the `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` method now preserves the additional info, so it doesn't suffer from the performance problem you've addressed.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Removed the sort and made it a function.

```
public static FileInfo GetOldestFile(string directory)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        throw new ArgumentException();

    DirectoryInfo parent = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    FileInfo[] children = parent.GetFiles();
    if (children.Length == 0)
        return null;

    FileInfo oldest = children[0];
    foreach (var child in children.Skip(1))
    {
        if (child.CreationTime < oldest.CreationTime)
            oldest = child;
    }

    return oldest;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorting is `O(n log n)`.  Instead, why don't you just *enumerate* the directory?  I'm not sure what the C# equivalent of [`FindFirstFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[`FindNextFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28VS.85%29.aspx) is, but you want to do is:

- Keep the current lowest date and filename in a local variable.
- Enumerate the directory.

  - If the date on a given file is less than the local variable, set the local variable to the new date and filename.

Comment: There really isn't a FindFirst/Next.  It's wrapped into Directory.GetFiles.  But you're right that all you need is a linear search, which is straight O(n).

Comment: In that case I might even wonder if you could shave off a few cycles by pinvoking the native enumeration APIs...  There's no need to do extra memory allocation here to get them in a big array.  You still won't get better than `O(n)` (in that sense the DB suggestion is better), but you can get `O(n)` with a lower constant factor and that might be good enough.

Comment: Further the native enumeration APIs give you the time and the filename at the same time; it doesn't look like `GetFiles()` does.

Comment: @asveikau: P/Invoking will not improve performance. You can get full directory information by calling `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx

Comment: @280Z28 OK, but what about the memory allocation question?  These functions will allocate big blocks of memory that's not really needed with the native interfaces.

Comment: @asveikau: Memory allocation in the CLR is cheap - MUCH cheaper than calling out to the Windows API for a file system operation.

Comment: I am as you might guess not very well versed in managed code, but I assume the implementation of `GetDirectories` must take this "calling out to Win32" hit as well.  At any rate, I am only offering suggestions of things to try out and measure, not making any guarantee about what will yield better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, this worked perfectly on a directory of mine with 3000+ jpg files:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dpath);
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
FileInfo firstfile = rgFiles[0];
FileInfo lastfile = rgFiles[rgFiles.Length - 1];
DateTime oldestfiletime = firstfile.CreationTime;
DateTime newestfiletime = lastfile.CreationTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, would it not be easier to shell out to a hidden process and redirect the output stream to the input and use the `dir /o-d` which sorts by the date/time, using the dash reverses the operation....

**Edit:** here's a sample code to do this...quick and dirty...

```
public class TestDir
    {
        private StringBuilder sbRedirectedOutput = new StringBuilder();
        public string OutputData
        {
            get { return this.sbRedirectedOutput.ToString(); }
        }
        public void Run()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ps = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            ps.FileName = "cmd";
            ps.ErrorDialog = false;
            ps.Arguments = string.Format("dir {0} /o-d", path_name);
            ps.CreateNoWindow = true;
            ps.UseShellExecute = false;
            ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ps.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            using (System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
            {
                proc.StartInfo = ps;
                proc.Exited += new EventHandler(proc_Exited);
                proc.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                while (!proc.HasExited) ;
            }
        }

        void proc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("proc_Exited: Process Ended");
        }

        void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data != null) this.sbRedirectedOutput.Append(e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("proc_OutputDataReceived: Data: " + e.Data);
        }
    }
```

The very first 4 or 5 lines of the StringBuilder object `sbRedirectedOutput` can be chopped out,then after that line would contain the oldest filename and would be quite easy to parse out....

Comment: I don't see the benefit of this.

Comment: @Steven: the directory listing could be redirected to a string, and it's a matter of picking out the filename in the top of the listing...

Comment: "Look, would it not be easier..." Ummm... no.

Comment: `dir` would read in the whole directory to sort it, so there's no benefit over doing it yourself.

Comment: @gabe: I don't understand what you mean? Instead of having to read the directory into DirectoryInfo, and sorting this, this code I wrote is asynchronous, and reads in the directory which is redirected to a stringbuilder, the dir command sorts it, and is a matter of picking out the right filename from the top and bob's your uncle...why is that not feasible? Either hog up memory by reading in the DirectoryInfo yourself or do a simple shell out to do that task? Something's gotta give, something's gotta take...

Comment: When you just want the oldest file, you don't have to sort it. Just read over the directory once and return the lowest date you found, which is O(n). The dir command has no way of knowing you only care about the first result, so it has to perform a sort which is O(n lg n).

Comment: If I thought that doing dir was a good idea, I would run `cmd /d /c dir /b /o-d "{0}"` and terminate the process as soon as the first result came in.

Comment: @Gabe: the dir sort command switch does exactly that when shelling out to cmd.exe which is a hidden window...hence you are avoiding the O(n lg n) sort programmatically, as that is done externally via this code I supplied.....you're looking at it the wrong way or that you are not clear in what you're saying, you think that programatically a O(n lg n) is done in the C# code....which this answer shows *how to avoid the sorting programmatically*...

Comment: If you look at 280Z28's answer, you will see that it does not have to sort the directory. It looks at each directory entry exactly once, so it is O(n). The dir command will sort the whole directory, so it is O(n lg n). The point isn't to get something else to do the sorting for you, it's to avoid sorting altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C# routine that may do what you want by spawning a cmd shell execute a `dir /o:D` on the specified directory and returning the name of the first file found.

```
        static string GetOldestFile(string dirName)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            si.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            si.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process p = Process.Start(si);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"dir " + dirName + " /o:D");
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string[] splitters = { Environment.NewLine };
            string[] lines = output.Split(splitters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            // find first line with a valid date that does not have a <DIR> in it
            DateTime result;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < lines.Length)
            {
                string[] tokens = lines[i].Split(' ');
                if (DateTime.TryParse(tokens[0], out result))
                {
                    if (!lines[i].Contains("<DIR>"))
                    {
                        return tokens[tokens.Length - 1];
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }

            return "";
        }
```

Comment: I was thinking of going this route, but its about the same as a LINQ approach right?

Comment: Though this solution is correct, it is slow and filled with corner cases. Buyer beware.

Answer (score 0):

I also have thousands of files. To retrieve them in sorted order by the date modified, use either of these C# statements.

```
files = di.GetFiles("*.*").OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).ToArray();
files = di.GetFiles("*.*").OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime).ToArray();
```

To make it easier for the user to access the appropriate file, I display either of the following two lines. I have two windows open. One lists the files in descending order. The other list the files in ascending order. The descending order list is updated by Windows. The ascending order is not updated so the Hm key must be used to put the oldest file at the top of the list.

```
Console.WriteLine( "DateMod v (latest)");
Console.WriteLine( "DateMod ^ (oldest) Sel Hm");
```