# finding closest value in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, find

```
int[] array = new int[5]{5,7,8,15,20};

int TargetNumber = 13;
```

For a target number, I want to find the closest number in an array. For example, when the target number is 13, the closest number to it in the array above is 15. How would I accomplish that programmatically in C#?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

EDIT: Have adjusted the queries below to convert to using `long` arithmetic, so that we avoid overflow issues.

I would probably use [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)'s `MinBy` method:

```
var nearest = array.MinBy(x => Math.Abs((long) x - targetNumber));
```

Or you *could* just use:

```
var nearest = array.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long) x - targetNumber)).First();
```

... but that will sort the whole collection, which you really don't need. It won't make much difference for a *small* array, admittedly... but it just doesn't feel quite right, compared with describing what you're *actually* trying to do: find the element with the minimum value according to some function.

Note that both of these will fail if the array is empty, so you should check for that first.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there a way to alter MinBy version to return index instead of value?

Comment: @ManInMoon: The simplest approach would be to use `Select((value, index) => new { Value, Index })` to start with, then `MinBy` would return the pair containing the minimum value, and you could fetch the index that way.

Comment: What if I want to find closest number not only once, but several times. Does it change anything? And I don't want to call *OrderBy* for each number I want to find.

Comment: @rraszewski: Then *if* the array is potentially large, I'd probably use a binary search, assuming the input array is actually sorted to start with. It requires more code, but would be more efficient.

Answer (score 35):

If you're using .Net 3.5 or above LINQ can help you here:

```
var closest = array.OrderBy(v => Math.Abs((long)v - targetNumber)).First();
```

Alternatively, you could write your own extension method:

```
public static int ClosestTo(this IEnumerable<int> collection, int target)
{
    // NB Method will return int.MaxValue for a sequence containing no elements.
    // Apply any defensive coding here as necessary.
    var closest = int.MaxValue;
    var minDifference = int.MaxValue;
    foreach (var element in collection)
    {
        var difference = Math.Abs((long)element - target);
        if (minDifference > difference)
        {
            minDifference = (int)difference;
            closest = element;
        }
    }

    return closest;
}
```

Useable like so:

```
var closest = array.ClosestTo(targetNumber);
```

Comment: worth mantioning that this will work from .NET 4.0+, if I have less, may be a simple extension method would be good too.

Comment: @Tigran The OrderBy and First LINQ methods have been available since .Net 3.5. However I take your point, answer updated.

Comment: +1 for this. But I use a 3.5 and don't have that function. So it's better to have some "B" option.

Comment: also if you have an array with `{5,7,8,15,20}` and `targetNumber = 6`, closest will be 5 ; if array is `{7,5,8,15,20}` closest will be 7

Comment: @Tigran: *Which* function don't you have? If you're using .NET 3.5, you definitely have OrderBy and First - although you'll need a using directive for System.Linq.

Answer (score 25):

Both Jon and Rich gave great answers with `MinBy` and `ClosestTo`.  But I would never recommend using `OrderBy` if your intent is to find a single element.  It's far too inefficient for those kinds of tasks.  It's simply the wrong tool for the job.

Here's a technique that performs marginally better than MinBy, is already included in the .NET framework, but less elegant than MinBy: [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx)

```
var nearest = array.Aggregate((current, next) => Math.Abs((long)current - targetNumber) < Math.Abs((long)next - targetNumber) ? current : next);
```

As I said, not as elegant as Jon's method, but viable.

Performance on my computer:

1. For(each) Loops = fastest
2. Aggregate = 2.5x slower than loops
3. MinBy = 3.5x slower than loops
4. OrderBy = 12x slower than loops

Answer (score 5):

I found this really sexy approach years ago in Math.NET Numerics https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ which works with BinarySearch in the array. It was a good help in preparation for interpolations and works down to .Net 2.0:

```
public static int LeftSegmentIndex(double[] array, double t)
{
    int index = Array.BinarySearch(array, t);
    if (index < 0)
    {
        index = ~index - 1;
    }
    return Math.Min(Math.Max(index, 0), array.Length - 2);
}
```

Comment: Note that this not exactly answer the question. Using this with the OP's value, then providing `t = 13` actually returns index `2`, so value `8` and not the desired `15`.

Comment: Your are right, this is what is meant with "LeftSegment". Of course you have to check the distances to the two candidates on left and right afterwards. Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the closest value to the average

### very open style

```
public static double Miidi(double[] list)
{
    bool isEmpty = !list.Any();
    if (isEmpty)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        double avg = list.Average();
        double closest = 100;
        double shortest = 100;
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
            {
                double lgth = list[i] - avg;
                if (lgth < 0)
                {
                    lgth = lgth - (2 * lgth);
                }
                else
                    lgth = list[i] - avg;

                if (lgth < shortest)
                {
                    shortest = lgth;
                    closest = list[i];
                }
            }
        }

        return closest;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

Performance wise custom code will be more useful.

```
public static int FindNearest(int targetNumber, IEnumerable<int> collection) {
    var results = collection.ToArray();
    int nearestValue;
    if (results.Any(ab => ab == targetNumber))
        nearestValue = results.FirstOrDefault(i => i == targetNumber);
    else{
        int greaterThanTarget = 0;
        int lessThanTarget = 0;
        if (results.Any(ab => ab > targetNumber)) {
            greaterThanTarget = results.Where(i => i > targetNumber).Min();
        }
        if (results.Any(ab => ab < targetNumber)) {
            lessThanTarget = results.Where(i => i < targetNumber).Max();
        }

        if (lessThanTarget == 0) {
            nearestValue = greaterThanTarget;
        }
        else if (greaterThanTarget == 0) {
            nearestValue = lessThanTarget;
        }
        else if (targetNumber - lessThanTarget < greaterThanTarget - targetNumber) {
            nearestValue = lessThanTarget;
        }
        else {
            nearestValue = greaterThanTarget;
        }
    }
    return nearestValue;
}
```