# Sorting Nearest Numbers by using array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

There is an array

```
int[] array = new int[]{6,4,10,7,7,9};
```

and a number 8.

I wanna sort the array around 8 by nearest number.

the nearest numbers : 9,7,7,10,6,4 respectively

because 9-1 = 8, 7+1 = 8, 7+1 = 8, 10-2 = 8, 6+2 = 8, 4+4 = 8

how can I sort this numbers. 
any idea?

Comment: Possible. Since I remember a similar question

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Finding Nearest Number in Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120944/c-sharp-finding-nearest-number-in-array)

Comment: It is also same question from `user1328639` with very nice answers

Comment: @L.B: Although i've already voted to close, that's not a duplicate. He wanted the closest value there and here order by distance from a given value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = array.OrderBy(i => Math.Abs(i - value))
             .ThenBy(i => i < value)
             .ToArray();
```

Comment: Doesn't the OP want numbers greater than the target value to be placed before numbers less than the target number if the difference is the same?

Comment: yeah, i.e. this produces `7,7,9,6,10,4` but the OP wants `9,7,7,10,6,4`

Comment: @devdigital: Corrected before you've commented. Anyway, why the downvote when OP hasn't mentioned that it matters? It might be simply a bad example.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ahh, forgot to refresh +1

Comment: @devdigital According to specs it should sort based on how near; there is no definition for a tiebreaker; it is therefore indeterminate.

Comment: The example seems specific enough to imply the behavior I described

Comment: @devdigital The fact that one example, written out by hand, happened to follow that behavior does not make it a part of the definition.  I wouldn't object to adding the additional sort when behavior is undefined, but demanding doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of my question suggests a peremptory requirement over a clarification of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
int nearbyNumber = 8;
var query = array.OrderBy(number => Math.Abs(number - nearbyNumber ));
```

You can call `ToArray` if you really need an array.

If you really want to sort the array in place you can make a custom Comparer object and use `Array.Sort`, but that's more work...

Comment: Not so much more work: `Array.Sort(array, (a, b) => { int c = Math.Abs(n - a).CompareTo(Math.Abs(n - b)); return c != 0 ? c : b.CompareTo(a); });`

Comment: @digEmAll `Array.Sort` doesn't take a `Func<T,T,int>` it takes an `IComparer`.  That lambda doesn't implement that interface.

Comment: Actually there's an overload of Sort taking a delegate -->[LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Also, I tested that line of code ;)

Comment: Hmm, hadn't seen that used before.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = new int[] { 6, 4, 10, 7, 7, 9 };
int target = 8;
var values = array.OrderBy(i => Math.Abs(i - target)).ToArray();
```

**EDIT** I had this answer super fast, then SO stopped me with some captcha's asking if was human. Thanks a lot SO! :)

Comment: yeah, that captcha is a pain, but this produces 7,7,9,6,10,4 and the OP wants 9,7,7,10,6,4

Comment: his example output is in that order, but he doesn't say he has to be in that order.

Comment: given that this is the second time he posted this question and the only difference between the two questions is that he added the numbers in that specific order, then he must want them in that order. But i'm not nit-picking, i was just saying...