# I try to find nearest double in Array

Tags: c#

I try to follow the code here:

[C# Finding Nearest Number in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120944/c-sharp-finding-nearest-number-in-array)

but fail.

The only different from my code with the code there is in my code the MinBy is error (there is red underline) which show its an error in Visual Studio.

By the way, this is the the code that I write:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double[] array = new double[5] { 0.25, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7 };

            double TargetNumber = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            var nearest = array.MinBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - targetNumber));
            label1.Text = nearest.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Im new with C# things. Sorry for a noob question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add the `MoreLINQ` Nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/ - to get access to `MinBy`. _I have updated the post you linked to, to add that URL there._ Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui . Also remove `(long)`

Comment: You can NuGet "System.Interactive" to get a `MinBy` operator.

Comment: @mjwills, I update the code and instal the Nuget package. It solve the MinBy issue. But when I run the program and key in a value (0.3) at the text box and hit the button, It didnt give me the nearest number but something like "System.Collection.Generic.List'1[System.Double]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes implementing a library to use just one method sounds a little bit like an overkill (even if `MoreLINQ` is an amazing library)... this code should provide you the same result without using an external library, if it's a good solution for you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Double[] array = new Double[] { 0.25, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7 };
            Double targ = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            Double[] arraySorted = array.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x - targ)).ToArray();
            Int32 idx = Array.IndexOf(array,arraySorted.First());

            label1.Text = idx.ToString();

            Double arrayValue = array[idx];
            Int32 idxLower = 0;
            Int32 idxUpper = 0;

            if (targ == arrayValue)
                idxLower = idxUpper = idx;
            else
            {
                if (targ > arrayValue)
                {
                    idxLower = idx;
                    idxUpper = idx + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    idxLower = idx - 1;
                    idxUpper = idx;
                }
            }

            label2.Text = idxLower.ToString();
            label3.Text = idxUpper.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know whos downvote it. But as for the code, its simpler, but can I get it like, nearest upper/nearest lower?

Comment: Uhm what do you mean? You mean dealing with negative numbers?

Comment: As I see at the code given, it will give out the nearest value for example if the TargetNumber = 0.43,  it will select 0.4 as the nearest number, but if more than 0.45, it will select 0.5 as nearest number. 

Can I make the output to be always pick the upper/lower value. For example, if I put 0.42 or 0.48, the output will always be 0.5, It pick the nearest upper value.

Comment: With upper and lower, what should the function return if we are below the left extreme or above the right one?

Comment: Ok I added upper and lower bounds. However, until you don't tell me how to deal with lower and upper bound indices overflowing the array dimension, the code cannot be further improved. If you question satisfies your request, please accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You overcomplicate things. Here is your "bread-and-butter" helper method which finds the value from array `a` nearest to the passed value `d`:

```
private static double? FindNearestValue(IEnumerable<double> arr, double d)
{
    var minDist = double.MaxValue;
    double? nearestValue = null;

    foreach (var x in arr)
    {
        var dist = Math.Abs(x - d);
        if (dist < minDist)
        {
            minDist = dist;
            nearestValue = x;
        }
    }
    return nearestValue;
}
```

To use it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] array = new double[5] { 0.25, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7 };

    double TargetNumber = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    var nearest = FindNearestValue(array, TargetNumber);

    label1.Text = nearest.ToString(); // nulls are printed as empty string
}
```

For small arrays linear search has comparable speed to the binary search. If implementing binary search is problem for you and you're new to `c#` (didn't get used to LINQ power) then good-ol' `foreach` is your friend for now.