# C# Finding Nearest Value in a Generic Array?

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

Same as: [C# Finding Nearest Number in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120944/c-sharp-finding-nearest-number-in-array#10120978) but without necessarily having numbers

I am thinking about creating an extension method that would look like:

```
public static TSource ClosestTo<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source
    , TSource target
    , IComparer<TSource> comparer = null)
```

Of course we can add a converter from `TSource` to `int` and replicate the int compliant algorithm.

But I am wondering whether the same can be achieved with only comparisons without having to resort to the int conversion to be able to use `Math.Abs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, no - that signature doesn't provide enough information to determine "closeness".

`IComparer<T>` only allows you to compare two values to see whether one is greater, less than or equal to another. There's no concept of "distance".

With that signature you could return:

- A value that matches `target`
- A value that is less than `target` but is greater than any other value that is less than `target`
- A value that is greater than `target` but is less than any other value that is greater than `target`

That's assuming that `source` doesn't contain any values equal to each other.

So for example, given input of { 1, 6, 3, 7, 8, 10 } and a target of 4, you could return "3 and 6" - but you couldn't tell that 3 is closer to the target than 6 is.

Note that values may be comparable like this without there being a notion of "distance" at all in `IComparer<T>` or `IComparable<T>`. I'm not aware of any similar interface that *does* have that notion. For example, you can sort strings in an ordinal fashion, but would would the distance be between "fox" and "wombat"? You could potentially *construct* some notion of distance, but there could be multiple competing ones, and I suspect you'd run into problems of precision as the strings involved get longer and longer.

Comment: "You could potentially construct some notion of distance, but there could be multiple competing ones, and I suspect you'd run into problems of precision as the strings involved get longer and longer." Hence my initial idea of converting TSource to int, but true the IComparer<TSource> does not carry the distance information on its own.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret: Right. I've clarified the answer a bit - not only does `IComparer<T>` not have that, but I don't think there's a similar interface that does.

Comment: yes indeed, remains me my implementations of distribution sorts (piegon hole sorts) or anything that do not carry a distance info. 
I also ended up with TSource -> int + dictionary to keep equivalence once the sorts are done: 
https://github.com/ehouarn-perret/EhouarnPerret.CSharp.DSA/tree/master/EhouarnPerret.CSharp.DSA.Core/Algorithms/Sorting/Distribution