# How to copy latest file from multiple directory to single directory using ssis package?

Tags: ssis

I want to copy a latest created file(.orig) from multiple directories into one common directory using SSIS package.

The filename starts with PSAN* and wants copies only .orig file format.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a replacement for web searches
and tutorials. We can help you with specific problems with your code, but we
don't re-type tutorials or write the code for you. Please see [ask]. Do some
research, then [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]. What is
the problem with it? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to
happen instead? Any errors? Good luck!

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to improve your question. Show a worked example explaining your directory structure and what the final output should be.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code:

```
FileSystemInfo fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath).GetFileSystemInfos()
    .OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime).First();
```

at this URL:

[how to get the oldest file in a directory fast using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398625/how-to-get-the-oldest-file-in-a-directory-fast-using-net)

You can use this in a script task.

Comment: You can add a .CopyTo(newDirectory) to the end of that.